# First seekToTime, then fade in with setVolumeRampFromStartVolume

Tags: objective-c, xcode, audio, avplayer

I'm programming a music player app that allows users to prelisten to tracks before adding them to the queue (I use `AVQueuePlayer` for this).

If the user selects a song he wants to prelisten, the current song is faded out with `setVolumeRampFromStartVolume` and the selected song will begin to play. This works fine.

After the user is done with prelistening, the interrupted song will be restored and I seek back to the time when it was interrupted by the prelisten-track with `seekToTime:completionHandler`:

My code for this looks a little like this:

```
- (void)stopPreview
{
    if (previewInterruptedItem) {
        [self addMediaItemToUserQueue:previewInterruptedItem afterCurrentItem:YES];
        previewInterruptedItem = nil;

        [[self queuePlayer] advanceToNextItem];

        [[[self queuePlayer] currentItem] seekToTime:previewInterruptedTime
                                   completionHandler:^(BOOL finished){
            if (finished) {
                [self fadeVolumeIn:YES];
            }
        }];

    }
}

- (void)fadeVolumeIn:(BOOL)fadeIn
{
    float startVolume = 0.1;
    float endVolume = 1.0;

    if (!fadeIn) {
        startVolume = 1.0;
        endVolume = 0.0;
    }


    AVAssetTrack *audioTrack = [[[self queuePlayer].currentItem.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *params = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:audioTrack];

    CMTime currentTime = [[[self queuePlayer] currentItem] currentTime];

    [params setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:startVolume
                             toEndVolume:endVolume
                               timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(currentTime, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1))];

    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    audioMix.inputParameters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:params];

    [self queuePlayer].currentItem.audioMix = audioMix;
}
```

This doesn't not for some reason. If I remove the `seekTime` line it fades in nicely, but I really want the track to resume where it was paused.

I assume it has something to do with the `timeRange` but I can't figure it out. I hope you have an idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions. First, I'd set your fade before you do a seekToTime. Second I'd use a bigger timescale for your CMTimeMakeWithSeconds - maybe 60000 or so. See  http://warrenmoore.net/understanding-cmtime for more details of CMTime, the timescale is important as with your call your timeRange will only fall on exact second boundaries and not on fractions of a second.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @amergin. I tried both of your suggestions but unfortunately nothing worked. I still think it has something to do start time I set within CMTimeRangeMake ...

Comment: Have you tried examining the contents of currentTime after you create it?